# As per current salesforce update , 3DES cipher suite support for inbound TLS connections will be disabled, how will it impact existing prod orgs?

Tags: integration, critical-update

We have third party integrations in our orgs. So , need to know the impact of the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the integrations. 3DES is only one of several cipher suites that are used. During the TLS handshake, the client and server choose the most secure cipher that they have in common and use that. If 3DES is the *only* supported cipher, then connections will fail. Otherwise, there won't be any effect, as the connection will simply choose another available cipher. The large majority of TLS-enabled software won't be affected, but if the server was specifically configured to not support AES, then it may fail. I would imagine that most servers running today should already support it without any additional configuration, but this should be reviewed carefully by the IT department as soon as practical.

Comment: Actually , i'am new to salesforce integrations. So , as i understand your answer we need to check whether other cipher suites are supported by servers which connect to salesforce ? And can we handle it from salesforce side while sending/ receiving data?

Comment: @RohitC cipher options are chosen automatically from the Salesforce side. You must configure the other software, if necessary, to choose cipher support. There's nothing you can do in Apex code to influence the result. You can catch a CalloutException if you want to handle the error, but you can't fix it in Salesforce.